# Unable to link requirements to existing test cases

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, cmmi

We're using VSTS and the CMMI template for our project. I'm facing an issue on the board where I'm unable to link existing test cases to the requirement.

I've tried to

- Go to requirement level and add existing item and set the relation to 'Tested By' and added my test cases. I can see the linkage on the requirement level however the **test cases don't show on the Requirement Board.**
- Go to Test case level and add linkage to existing item and chose 'Requirement', still **test cases don't show on the Requirement Board.**

**Am I only able to add new test to a requirement but not link to existing test cases?**

Comment: I suspect you need to set the iteration/area on the newly linked test case.

Comment: @jessehouwing, sorry I should make it more clear. It's not shown on the 'Requirement board' (where we normally see tasks and test cases associated with a requirement)

Comment: I understand. And I suspect that the area/iteration setting of the test case doesn't match the board settings.

Comment: Tested on my side, everything works as expected. What about other projects? Do they have the same issue? You can try to create a new project to check if that still occurs with the new project.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but after 2 days, the linked test cases are shown on the requirement board now.....still puzzled about why it didn't show at the beginning.